# The javascript and css files cached by chrome do not belong to the same version

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache, etag

Have you ever encountered a situation where css and js cache are not the same version after the release.
js files come with an ETag, whereas css does not,
Both my js file and my css file cache different versions of content

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yNCQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWBVg.png)

Explain the phenomenon

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time when Internet speeds were slow, caching resources made sense but no more...

So I suggest you turn off the rendering engine’s cache via flags.

I use an old version of Chromium for tech reasons and these flags work for me:

```
--disk-cache-dir=Z:/abc 
--disk-cache-size=1 

--media-cache-dir=Z:/abc 
--media-cache-size=1
```

**NB:**

1: The directory Z:/abc is non-existent (fake) and this effectively prevents the engine from saving resources to disk, coupled with the very small cache size.

2: The rendering engine’s cache should not be confused with a browser cache that may exist and be configurable in the browser options. Don't turn this one off.

3: Chromium flags change often so if this is not working for you then you might want to research the matter based on your browser version.